# Concatenating text files next to each other (side by side)

Tags: python, text, concatenation

I have the following code for concatenating a series of text files. 
But i want the data in the files to be placed next to and not under the previous lines, how can i do that?

```
for dir in list(subdirs):
  splitdir = dir.split('/')
  # YOU WILL NEED TO EDIT THIS TO GRAB sub001
  splitdir_sub = splitdir[5]
  subnum=splitdir_sub[-4:]
  #  YOU WILL ALSO NEED TO EDIT THIS TO GRAB THE PART WITH THE RUNNUM
  splitdir_run = splitdir[8]
  runnum=splitdir_run[-1:]
  print("marging subject %s Run %s"%(subnum, runnum))
  filenames = ['/home/navotn/Exp5/participants/%s/preprocessed/1lev/block%sn.feat/white_matter.txt'%(subnum, runnum), '/home/navotn/Exp5/participants/%s/preprocessed/PPFSL/block%s/motion_assess/confound.txt'%(subnum, runnum)]
  with open("%s/%s/preprocessed/PPFSL/block%s/motion_assess/confoundWM.txt"%(fsfdir, subnum, runnum), 'w') as outfile:
      for fname in filenames:
          with open(fname) as infile:
              for line in infile:
                  outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Do your files end with an empty new line? Because that might be the reason.

Comment: @Navot Naor Try with file append 'a' instead of file write 'w'

Answer (score 0):

This code might give you what you need, provided that the input files have the same numbers of lines.

```
import os

fileNames = os.listdir('concatenate')
os.chdir('concatenate')
previous = fileNames[0]
for fileName in os.listdir('.')[1:]:
    with open(previous) as oldConcatenate, open(fileName) as nextFile, open('new.txt', 'w') as newConcatenate:
        while True:
            oldLine = oldConcatenate.readline().strip()
            if not oldLine:
                break
            nextLine = nextFile.readline().strip()
            newConcatenate.write(oldLine + nextLine + '\n')
    if previous != fileNames[0]:
        os.remove('concatenated.txt')
    os.rename('new.txt', 'concatenated.txt')
    previous = 'concatenated.txt'
```

The code concatenates the second file to the first and keeps that as file 'concatenated.txt' then adds the third file to this and again keeps this file as 'concatenated.txt' and so on.